# Trying to start the kubernetes in Docker-Desktop but it's stuck

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

***Update***
The issue is resolved.

1. I shutdown docker desktop.
2. Deleted C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop and .kube folder
3. Restarted docker desktop
4. reset docker desktop to factory defaults
5. and restarted it again and it worked.

I have started learning Kubernetes and Dockers yesterday. I installed Docker-Desktop today and my docker container is running. When i check the enable kubernetes option on Docker-Desktop it's not running. It just shows me a loading and below it just shows kubernete starting.
[Photo of my Docker Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJcyo.png)
**What i have tried:**

1. Uninstalling Docker Desktop and reinstalling it
2. Reset Kubernetes Cluster
3. Reset to Factory default

I have tried other solutions too which i found here on stackflow like:

1. Running it as an Administrator
2. Run this on powershell and then try to start kubernetes
   `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("KUBECONFIG", $HOME + "\.kube\config", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)`

But None of the solutions is trying to fix the problem im having.

**Addition Information:**

1. Im running Docker Desktop on Windows 10 pro
2. Docker Version: 2.2.0.5 Kubernetes version: v1.15.5

Comment: you could add your resolution as an answer to this question, and mark it as the answer. This would be more in keeping with the site standards. I am facing a similar issue on MacOS at the moment and I'll try out your approach for my system. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### Just follow these steps

1. stop docker for desktop
2. remove the folder `~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/pki`

```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/pki
```

3. start docker for destkop

Found [the solution here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3594#issuecomment-621487150)

And given that every time I try to start "Docker for Desktop" Kubernetes get stuck, to better investigate for me was useful remove the kube autostart from the configuration.

Just edit the file:

```
~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json
```

And change `kubernetesEnabled` value to `false`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it!
I deleted the config file i.e ~/.kube/config then I uninstalled the app through the Troubleshoot window. I reinstalled and enabled kubernetes **which required the internet to download the necessary files** and after a while kubernetes was running. I believe **its due to the internet connection during the installation of kubernetes files** that causes problems.[image: Here is the Troubleshoot window where you can access the uninstall button]

Answer (score 2):

Your update is right. That's what worked for me (on Windows 10) :

1. Shutdown Docker Desktop
2. Delete .kube folder (path : C:\Users\YourUserName\.kube)
3. Restart Docker Desktop
4. Reset Docker Desktop (press the scarab button (or also, debug or troubleshoot button) and click on "Reset to factory defaults")
5. Shutdown Docker Desktop
6. Restart Docker Desktop
7. Now, in the **settings** and in **Kubernetes tab**, Enable again Kubernetes (Check "Enable Kubernetes" option)

That's what worked for me and hope it's gonna be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to follow :

1. Quit Dockerdesktop
2. remove ~/.kube/config
   And ~/.kube/cache/*
3. restart start the docker desktop.

If you are behind a corporate vpn. then make sure you are able to configure proxy for the internet access in docker destop in preferences->Proxy. or you can disconnect from vpn and let the kubernates cluster setup for the first time. After that you can configure the proxy.

Comment: Additionally if your kube configs are set to be read only, it will prevent Kubernetes on Docker Desktop from starting.